# How to get IP when using Network Service Discovery code

Tags: android

I try to use the "Network Service Discovery" sample code to find service.
The source provided [here](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html).

The class NsdHelper discovery service code as below:

```
public void onServiceFound(NsdServiceInfo service) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Service discovery success" + service);
    if (!service.getServiceType().equals(SERVICE_TYPE)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Unknown Service Type: " + service.getServiceType());
    } else if (service.getServiceName().equals(mServiceName)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Same machine: " + mServiceName);
    } else if (service.getServiceName().contains(mServiceName)){
        mNsdManager.resolveService(service, mResolveListener);
    }
}
```

I try use "service.getHost()", but it get null.
How can I get the IP of each services?

Comment: When you [registerService()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.1_r1.2/android/net/nsd/NsdManager.java#454) you're passing `NsdServiceInfo` as parameter, so if [setHost(..)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.1_r1.2/android/net/nsd/NsdServiceInfo.java#86) wasn't called the address is `null`. The [NsdServiceInfo(..)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.1_r1.2/android/net/nsd/NsdServiceInfo.java#44) constructor doesn't set the address.

Comment: I use this method to discovery avahii services, not service registed by registerService. Is this can use?

Comment: So you're not the one who registers the service, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right\.

Comment: Well, my 1st comment is yet valid. If a 3rd party code doesn't "stick to the rule" you might get unexpected results like the one you've got...

Comment: I want to discover's service is create by avahii. And other bonjour browser tool all can get the information. So I think it is fit the rule.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128894/discussion-between-onik-and-brian).